# Binary Typing Problem

Tags: haskell, bson

I am trying to work with the [Haskell Bson](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bson/0.1.6/doc/html/Data-Bson-Binary.html) and I want to save and load them. The saving seems to be no problem, but I get a typing error with the `Binary.get` functions.

Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}
module Database.Axiom where

import Data.Bson (Document, Field)
import Data.Bson.Binary (putDocument, getDocument)
import Data.Binary as B (Binary(..), decodeFile, encodeFile)
import Control.Monad (liftM2)

instance Binary Document where
    put = putDocument
    get = getDocument

data Collection = Collection {
        collectionName :: ByteString,
        collectionDocs :: [Document]
    }

instance Binary Collection where
    put (Collection name docs) = B.put name >> B.put docs
    get = liftM2 Collection B.get B.get -- < Here is the type error
```

Which leads to this error:

```
Database/Axiom.hs:24:39:
    Overlapping instances for Binary [Field]
      arising from a use of `B.get'
    Matching instances:
      instance Binary a => Binary [a] -- Defined in Data.Binary
      instance Binary Document -- Defined at Database/Axiom.hs:13:10-24
    In the third argument of `liftM2', namely `B.get'
    In the expression: liftM2 Collection B.get B.get
    In an equation for `get': get = liftM2 Collection B.get B.get
```

The problem is that `Document` is merely a synonym of `[Field]`. But I need an instance for `Binary Document`, as there are no functions to serialize a single `Field`. And moreover, [BSON](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bson/0.1.6/doc/html/Data-Bson.html) does not export any instances for `Binary Field`, so I am completely confused why this error happens in the first place.

I tried it with strict type declaration and then to use a self made `get` method, but a `get :: [Document]` only works nicely when there's a `get :: Document` method.

So, anyone can help me, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altough a little subjective, I think the cleanest and most robust way to fix is is to add a `newtype` for `Document`. Something like:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.Bson (Document, Field)
import Data.Bson.Binary (putDocument, getDocument)
import Data.Binary as B (Binary(..), decodeFile, encodeFile)
import Control.Monad (liftM2)

newtype CollectionDoc = CollectionDoc {unCollectionDoc :: Document}

instance Binary CollectionDoc where
    put = putDocument . unCollectionDoc
    get = CollectionDoc <$> getDocument

data Collection = Collection {
        collectionName :: ByteString,
        collectionDocs :: [CollectionDoc]
    }

instance Binary Collection where
    put (Collection name docs) = B.put name >> B.put docs
    get = liftM2 Collection B.get B.get
```

should work. In addition, `newtype` wrappers are completely optimized away, so there is no overhead at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define the instance for `Document`; just call `getDocument` instead of `B.get` (which I see no need for qualifying with the `B.`) in your `get` definition for `Collection`.

Comment: That won't work, because the second `get` is of type `Get [Document]`.

Comment: @Scán: `[getListOf](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cereal/0.3.3.0/doc/html/Data-Serialize-Get.html#v:getListOf) getDocument` will do the trick then if you don't want a newtype like jaspervdj describes.